# Ocurre ERROR SIGSEGV

Tags: c#

Se trata del inicio del código para Djikstra Shortest Paths, pero me da el error SIGSEGV...

¿A que debiera inicializar Graph?

El programa no se ejecuta hasta llegar a  esta línea (sin haber dado el error):

```
for (int j=0; j < Nodes; ++j)
```

Este es mi código:

```
int main() {
    
    
    int Nodes, Start_Node;
    double Density;
    vector <int> Output_Distances(Nodes);
    // input Number of Nodos, Densidad, to generate random matrix
    cout << "Enter number of Nodes: " << endl; 
    cin >>  Nodes; 
    cout << "Enter Graph Edges Density: " << endl ;
    cin >>  Density; 
    cout << "Enter Start Node: "  << endl;
    cin >> Start_Node;
    
    vector <int>* graph; // Declares graph to fill out with edges

    srand(time(0)); // seed rand

        
    for (int i=0; i < Nodes; ++i) // loop to fill the matrix with false or true, randomly with probability less than Density
        for (int j=0; j < Nodes; ++j)
            if (i==j) graph[i][j]=false; //diagonal - no loop edge
```

Gracias!

Comment: En una violacion de segmento,te aconsejo que lo analizes con `gdb` para  que veas como esta trabajando la ejecucion de codigo en la memoria...y puedas sacar tus propias conclusiones a partir de ahi.

Answer (score 0):

No has inicializado el vector:

Eso, en ese punto es nulo.

```
vector <int>* graph;
```

Aquí estás accediendo a la posición **`i, j`** de un vector, en vez de una matriz.

```
if (i==j) graph[i][j]=false
```